# How can I recognize the x in the string "x-ring closing10.00x10.00mm" and replace it with a space

Tags: python, replace, token

Good evening,

I'm trying to write a script which will recognize dimensions in a string (for example: 10x10x12 or 25X35X4 G) and will automatically replace the x with a white space. So that the result will be 10 10 12 or 25 35 4.

The strings in which I am searching will have more information in them which can also contain an x which should not be replaced.

I am lost on how to achieve this, hopefully someone knows how i can tackle this problem.

Comment: `will have more information in them which can also contain an x which should not be replaced.` Do you mean only capital `X`'s should be replaced? Please elaborate and provide a full example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This replaces x/X if following and followed by a digit.

```
>>> s = '1x2X3, 10x10x12, 25X35X4 G, XXX expert, 3x world champ, great x2'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)x(?=\d)', ' ', s, flags=re.I)
'1 2 3, 10 10 12, 25 35 4 G, XXX expert, 3x world champ, great x2'
```

Comment: excuse the pedantry: is it `followed by a digit` or `followed by a number` ?

Comment: Digit, or both, depending on what you mean.

Comment: a number is made of digits (visually speaking). You have answered in the comment, I take it as `at least one digit` then. Upvoted

Comment: This worked really well for my dataset, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Checking if  `x` is preceded by a digit should be sufficient in your case:

```
import re

print(re.sub("(?<=\d)x", " ", "foox barx 10x10x12"),re.I)
foox barx 10 10 12
```

Comment: This solution is clever, just looking if x is precedet by a digit.

Comment: This also replaces `foo 10xbar` with `foo 10 bar`.

Comment: @gre_gor, where do you see that in the input or why would you think it would be there? Your regex checks for three digits, what if there are only 2

Comment: Also possibly `screws: 5x` to `screws: 5 `.

Comment: "3x world champion", "P90x is great"

Comment: Re: "all the x's should be lowercase" - they're not. The question contains examples with both cases.

Comment: @StefanPochmann,  so in that vein try `s = "some xXx dim: 10x12, 25X35X4 p90x3"` with your own regex, we can all find ways to break the regexes, that is why letting the OP i.e the person that has the data decide what works

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with a lookbehind and backreferences:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'x-ring closing10.00x10.00mm'
>>> s2 = 'x-ring closing10.00x10.00x5.00mm'
>>> s3 = 'dimensions 1 x 4 x3'
>>> re.sub(r'((?<=\d))\s*[xX]\s*(\d)', r'\1 \2', s)
'x-ring closing10.00 10.00mm'
>>> re.sub(r'((?<=\d))\s*[xX]\s*(\d)', r'\1 \2', s2)
'x-ring closing10.00 10.00 5.00mm'
>>> re.sub(r'((?<=\d))\s*[xX]\s*(\d)', r'\1 \2', s3)
'dimensions 1 4 3'
```

This will find instances of "a number, possible whitespace, then `x`, possible whitespace, then a number" and replace them with "that first number, a space, then the second number."

Answer (score 0):

Use regex expressions from the `re` module.

```
import re

def repl_dim(m):
    return " ".join(m.groups())

s = "some xXx dim: 10x10x12, 25X35X4"

print re.sub("(\d+)x(\d+)x(\d+)", repl_dim, s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

prints

```
some xXx dim: 10 10 12, 25 35 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# remove x that is between ints or floats
st = "10.10x10.101 44x33 bxb x199"
st = re.sub(r'(\d+(\.\d+)?)x(\d+(\.\d+)?)',r'\1 \3',st)

print(st)

10.10 10.101 44 33 bxb x199
```